# Python - reading a path to a file name

Tags: python, argv

I'm attempting this Code Eval challenge in Python called Predict the Number:

https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/125/

My problem (I think) has something to do with reading the input file. It says "Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename." AFAIK, reading such a file involves import sys and sys.argv[1]. It tests OK, but fails the submission. I think my code is free of logic errors, but here it is. Perhaps I'm not using argv correctly...?

EDIT: When I submit, I get the following error: "CodeEval Error: Process was aborted after 10 seconds." Does this just mean my code is too inefficient to finish?

```
import sys

# increment the given int, returns 0, 1, or 2
def inc(num):
    return (num + 1) % 3

# double the length of the input sequence by incrementing
# each int from old half to create the new half
def double(old):
    new = ''
    for i in old:
        new += str(inc(int(i)))
    return old + new

# returns the int (0, 1, or 2) of the input index
def position(n):
    global sequence
    while len(sequence) < n:
        sequence = double(sequence)
    return int(sequence[n])

# print each int in the given position of each line in the file
def predict(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in file.readlines():
        if len(line) > 0:
            print position(int(line))
    file.close()

# initialize the sequence
sequence = '0'

# call the program with the first command-line argument
predict(sys.argv[1])

# clean exit
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you post your error and possibly your intended output?

Comment: Oh, of course. It told me "CodeEval Error: Process was aborted after 10 seconds." Does that just mean my code is horribly inefficient?

Comment: Yes. Most likely its too slow

Comment: @kroolik No, its highly unlikely, that this code is too slow.

Comment: I checked this code from the link's example and it runs fine. What does your input file look like?

Comment: Could it be that the file is (very) large and reading it all into memory with `for line in file.readlines():` causes a slowdown due to swapping or other restrictions? Just use `for line in file:` to read lines on (buffered) demand at the very least.

Comment: I'm not sure how big the input file is, since it's only passed through on submission. But when it checks a given index, that index could be up to 3000000000. The real problem is how to repeatedly search a long string of integers.

Comment: If the index is 3,000,000,000 then even if python stores characters as 1 byte in memory (I'm pretty sure it's at least 2) then your sequence string would grow to be 2.79 GB.  It's likely you aren't given that much memory for the code eval challenge and it is swapping.  I doubt you are going to be able to construct the entire sequence in memory.